# How to set the Google Map zoom level to show all the markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How do I set the zoom level to show all the markers on Google Maps?

In my Google Map there are different markers in different positions. I want to set google map zoom level based on the range of markers (that means in the view of google map, i want to see all markers)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps getBoundsZoomLevel Demo</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body onunload="GUnload()"> 

   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
      var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
      var markerBounds = new GLatLngBounds();

      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
         var randomPoint = new GLatLng( 39.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20, 
                                       -77.00 + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

         map.addOverlay(new GMarker(randomPoint));
         markerBounds.extend(randomPoint);
      }

      map.setCenter(markerBounds.getCenter(), 
                    map.getBoundsZoomLevel(markerBounds));
   }
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

We are creating 10 random points in the above example and then passing each point to `GLatLngBounds.extend()`. Finally we get the correct zoom level with `GMap2.getBoundsZoomLevel()`.

[image: Google Maps getBoundsZoomLevel Demo]

Answer (score 26):

> set the Google Map zoom level to show all the markers?

## Maps API v3

1. get markers
2. get boundaries of markers
3. set center on map by fitting it to marker boundaries

---

```
var markers = [markerObj1, markerObj2, markerObj3];

var newBoundary = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for(index in markers){
  var position = markers[index].position;
  newBoundary.extend(position);
}

map.fitBounds(newBoundary);
```

The code above will automaticlly center and zoom your map so that all markers are visible.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using API version 3 you can replace

```
map.setCenter(markerBounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(markerBounds));
```

with

```
map.fitBounds(markerBounds).
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `extend` method of the [GLatLngBounds](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLngBounds) object, which represents a rectangle on the map.

```
var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
```

Loop around all the [points](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng) on your map, extending the bounds of your GLatLngBounds object for each one.

```
bounds.extend(myPoint);
```

Finally you can use your bounds object to set the centre and zoom of your map (where `map` is your map object)

```
map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
```